# Подтверждение обработки сообщения из очереди RabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq

Организую для взаимосвязи приложений очередь.
Использую библиотеку **aio-pika** для того, чтобы получать сообщения.

**Проблема:**
Сообщения успешно получаю и обрабатываю их, НО по средствам мониторинга вижу, что сообщения переходят из статуса **Ready** в статус **Unranked** и всё.
Т.е. мой код не отправлят подтверждение обработки. Поэтому при перезапуске слушателя, все сообщения отправлять по новой.

**Вопрос:**
Как сделать подтверждение обработки сообщение в библиотеке aio-pika?
Или здесь нужно действовать иначе?

**Инструменты:** 
aio-pika (latest): 
https://aio-pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

RabbitMQ: 3.8.9 
Erlang: 23.1.3 
Авторизован как админ.

**Код отправителя:**

```
import asyncio
import aio_pika
from aio_pika import DeliveryMode


async def main(loop):
    connection = await aio_pika.connect_robust(
        "amqp://admin:pass@127.0.0.1/", loop=loop
    )

    routing_key = 'events_queue'

    channel = await connection.channel()

    data = {
        'key': 'val',
    }
    import json

    await channel.default_exchange.publish(
        aio_pika.Message(
            body=json.dumps(data).encode(),
            app_id='999',
            delivery_mode=DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT,
        ),
        routing_key=routing_key,
    )

    await connection.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
    loop.close()
```

**Код слушателя:**

```
import asyncio
import json

from aio_pika import IncomingMessage, connect

from settings import (
    RABBIT_URL, ROUTING_KEY
)


async def on_message(message: IncomingMessage):
    print('Get: {}'.format(message.body))

    try:
        message_data = json.loads(message.body)
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        return
    
    print(message_data)

async def main(_loop):
    connection = await connect(RABBIT_URL, loop=_loop)
    channel = await connection.channel()
    await channel.set_qos()
    queue = await channel.declare_queue(
        ROUTING_KEY, durable=True,
    )
    await queue.consume(on_message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(main(loop))
    loop.run_forever()
```

**Запускаю RabbitMQ в докере:**

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  rabbit:
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=pass
    ports:
      - 15673:15672
      - 5672:5672
```

Comment: https://aio-pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rabbitmq-tutorial/2-work-queues.html#message-acknowledgment

Comment: @Mike Да, то что нужно. Оформите в виде ответа, чтобы я мог его Вам зачесть.